# Why does git require me to commit or stash local changes before doing a pull

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I made a change to a file in my local working copy and the same file has been modified in the remote repo. When I do a git pull, git gives the message, "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
foo.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge."

I know how to solve this issue, but I am not completely clear why this happens. So, if I do a git pull (which is git fetch  followed by git merge), then git will first bring the remote file changes to my local (and hence I lose my local changes) and then do the merge, is this what happens?

Also, in the same scenario, instead of a git pull, I did a git fetch first. This caused no issue, but when I did a git merge, I got the same message from git about losing local changes. So, that means that git fetch does not bring the remote changes to local, only when I try to do the merge is when the local working copy is replaced by the remote changes?

Comment: "*…git fetch does not bring the remote changes to local…?*" It doesn't. `git fetch` brings commits/tags/blobs from the remote repository to the local repository and updates **local remote-tracking branches** but it doesn't update files. Only `git checkout/merge/rebase/reset` update files in the working tree.

Comment: Restating what @phd already said, I like to think of 3 buckets: 1.) The commits on the remote server. 2.) My *copy* of the commits on the remote server as of the last time I fetched. 3.) My local working file system for a checked out branch/commit.  So, in the context of a `pull`, `fetch` copies from #1 to #2, and `merge` copies from #2 to #3. It's the `merge` that modifies your working files, and is what prompts the error.

Comment: @TTT, clarification regarding the buckets you mention, 1) The commits on the remote server, i.e. the remote repo? 2) My copy of the commits on the remote server ..., i.e., copy of the remote repo on my local? And merge copies from #2 to #3 but also to my local repo (bucket 4) as well?

Comment: @racerX Right. I didn't specify where your local commits sit that you haven't pushed yet. I'd probably put them in bucket #2: My copy of the commits on the remote server as the last time I fetched, and also my local commits that I haven't pushed yet. #3 is intended not to be commits but the file system which matches one commit in bucket #2. When you merge, you update branch pointers in bucket #2 and potentially make a new commit. Merge also updates your currently checked out branch/commit (bucket #3) and this is what changes your file system (and errors if it conflicts with pending changes).

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, `pull` = `fetch` + `merge`, more or less.<sup>1</sup>  The problem here is that `git merge` works with *commits*.  What's in your working tree are *files in the host OS's file system*.  These files may well have come *out* of some commit, but they are not in and of themselves a commit.  In a very real and important sense, your working tree files are not *in* Git at all!  So `git merge` won't work with them.

Peculiarly, if you set the second command to be `rebase`, Git has an "autostash" option where it will stash, rebase, and then un-stash.  Git does not have an option to do this with merge, even though it makes just as much sense here.  I recommend *avoiding* `git stash` due to its many rather awful failure modes, but it actually works quite well *most* of the time.  So if you choose rebase instead of merge, you can run `git pull` without committing first!  Many people like this, and also like the `git pull --rebase` work-flow.  If you find yourself in this camp, consider configuring your `git pull` to use rebase and your rebase to use autostash (but don't say I didn't warn you when the stash command bites you in some sensitive  anatomical area).

---

<sup>1</sup>You get to specify the second step of `git pull`: it's one of merge or rebase, but you choose which one.  There's also a special corner case with fetching into a totally empty repository or orphan branch, where the second step is actually just checkout/switch.